# Updating a website through SSH

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, command-line, terminal

I'm only partially familiar with shell and my command line, but I understand the usage of * when uploading and downloading files.

My question is this: If I have updated multiple files within my website's directory on my local device, is there some simple way to re-upload every file and directory through the put command to just update every single file and place files not previously there?

I'd imagine that i'd have to somehow
`put */` (to put all of the directories)
`put *` (to put all of the files)
and change permissions accordingly
It may also be in my best interests to first clear the directory to I have a true update, but then there's the problem of resetting all permissions for every file and directory.  I would think it would work in a similar manner, but I've had problems with it and I do not understand the use of the -r recursive option.

Comment: why not use rsync or something similar?

Comment: Thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically such functionality is perfected within the **[rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)** tool. And that tool can also be used in a "secure shell way"; as lined out in this [tutorial](http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/index.html).

As an alternative, you could also look into [sshfs](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-mount-remote-directory-filesystems-with-sshfs-on-linux/). That is a utility that allows you to "mount" a remote file system (using ssh) in your local system. So it would be completely transparent to rsync that it is syncing a local and a remote file system; for rsync, you would just be syncing to different directories!

Long story short: don't even think about implementing such "sync" code yourself. Yes, rsync itself requires some *studying*, as many unix tools it is extremely powerful; thus you have to be very diligent when using it. But thing is: this is a robust, well tested tool. The time required to learn about it will pay out pretty quickly.